# Count comments to each recension?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need someone to help me with this problem. My head doesn't want to think straight today.

So, i have a table named "recensions", and another named "comments". In each table, i have a column named "amne_id". This would make so i could connect the comments to the correct recension.

Now, on my first page, i simply get all the recensions with the code:

```
$rec = $this->db->get('recensions');
```

What i want is to count how many comments each recension has. But i have no idea how. I guess i maybe should use JOIN and num_rows()?

Please ask if you dont understand, so i can explain better.

Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't know how it will be in Codeigniter but the problem is of JOIN LIKE 'SELECT count(rec.amne_id) as tot_comments from recensions as rec JOIN comments as com ON rec.amne_id = com.amne_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count, recensions.anme_id as recension_id')
->from('recensions')
->join('comments','recensions.anme_id = comments.anme_id','left')
->group_by('anme_id');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Should give you the recensions id and the comment count for that id.

then loop:

```
foreach($result->result() as $row){
    echo "Recension id $row->recension_id has $row->count comments<br />";
}
```

Comment: Should i replace "$rec = $this->db->get('recensions');" with what you just wrote?

Comment: Up to you. If you don't want all the results then replace it. If you want to keep all the recensions, don't replace it. What I posted will just give you an object with the recension.anme_id and the count of comments for that anme_id.

Comment: How should i print out the result then? Using a foreach-loop or? Sorry for my little knowledge, im new into Codeigniter :)

Comment: Yup. Just use the standard Active Record stuff: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html I updated the answer with an example using aliasing.

Comment: Oh thank you! Just a fast question: What does "count" come from in "$row->count"? I can't see that variable anywhere?

Comment: No prob. Count comes from the alias: `$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count...`. you could call it whatever you want: `$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as sandwich...` would mean you'd use `$row->sandwich` in the loop :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19556/discussion-between-zacharias-and-stormdrain)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the database connector you are using, but in pure SQL (assuming the `connection recensions.id=comments.anme_id` connection), try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(comments.id), anme_id
FROM recensions
LEFT JOIN comments on comments.anme_id=recensions.id
GROUP BY anme_id
```

Comment: Hm, when i try this code, i got an error. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)"

Answer (score 0):

Like this??

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recensions");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$amne_id = $row{"amne_id"};
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE amne_id='$amne_id'");
$total_comments = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
echo $total_comments;
}
```